# Is it possible that after changing of DNS A record site is loaded from new IP, but scripts from old one?

Tags: dns

Is it possible that after changing of DNS A record, site content is loaded from new IP, but scripts, css or images from old one? i.e. that web page is requested from single domain name, but loaded from 2 IPs?
All this static content is referenced by relative URLs, like '/scripts/admin.js'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I am aware of... If your browser has been told that www.xxx.com is located at ip 1.1.1.1, be it by DNS, HOSTS, whatever, then that is where is will request from.

If you are experiencing this issue, the most likely candidate is that the browser has some cached copies of static scripts such as CSS, JS, static html pages and this is what you are seeing.

A complete clear of your borwser cache should resolve this issue.

Also, it is worth notnig that it is possible for one DNS name to have multiple IPs if the IP is actually the address of a [load balancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Load_Balancing) or a [round robin service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't likely that the content is being loaded from two different sites, unless you load the HTML and JS from different domain names (like www.domain.com and scripts.domain.com)

The more likely explanation is that the js is cached in your browser.